# Remember filter for the need answer tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav

I often switch from the <kbd>new</kbd> to the <kbd>need answer</kbd> tab and I *always* set the same filters... I would **LOVE** if SO was able to remind it.

Of course, I could make a favorite in my browser, but I tend to be *lazy* and I don't like the idea of moving my mouse outside the website borders.

I know that the filters are temporary stored via the url: when I set it in the <kbd>need answer</kbd> tab and goes back to the <kbd>new</kbd> tab I can see in the url `http://stackoverflow.com/?tagFilter=favorite` but as soon as I click on the SO logo to go back to the main page, it's lost.

Comment: @Sklivvz I don't see *how* it's completed...